# Child dataGrid dataContext is being set to parent dataGrid causing binding Error

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a parent and Child DataGrid as:

```
 <DataGrid Name="DispositionNCRsGrid"
                              ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource MainDataGridItemStyle}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ParentSource}"
                               >
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                       <DataGrid SelectionMode="Single"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding MyItemSource}"
                                   Style="{DynamicResource MainDataGridStyle}" 
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
```

Now the problem is Child Grid is looking `MyItemSource` inside `ParentSource` instead of current viewmodel.

How do I reset the Child dataGrid to access the data from my current ViewModel

Comment: so you want detail `DataGrid` to take `MyItemSource` from the same source that parent `DataGrid` takes `ParentSource`?

Comment: @dkozl,Yes , I want the child to get MyItemSource  from the same VM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get `MyItemSource` for detail `DataGrid` from the same view model that main `DataGrid` takes `ParentSource` then you can use `RelativeSource` binding and go up the visual tree to find parent `DataGrid` and use its `DataContext`

```
ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=DataContext.MyItemSource}"
```